# How to subtract a set of two queries and get the answer of the same as a number?

Tags: sql

The question is as follows:

Find the difference between the total number of CITY entries in the table and the number of distinct CITY entries in the table.
The STATION table is described as follows:

[image]

> I tried to query the same using the MINUS function, however it didn't
> work.

```
SELECT COUNT(CITY) 
MINUS
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(CITY)
FROM STATION
```

Could someone please explain it to me as to why I'm wrong and as to how I should go about solving this?

The output should come out to be 13.

*PS: I don't have the data. I only have the structure. This is a Hacerkrank Problem.*

Comment: MINUS is a set operator, like UNION. You are trying to take one number from another number so you need to use the - operator (like the + operator)

Comment: I don't understand why was this question closed an down-voted. The question was clear, the asker attempted to solve it and reached out to us after failing. This seems to be a perfectly legitimate use of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee3af8/2

Sample schema and data:

```
create table station(city varchar(12));

insert into station(city)
values
('a'),
('a'),
('b'),
('b'),
('c');
```

**Expectation**: Since there are 5 elements in total and 3 distinct values, their difference should be 2. So, let's see the query:

```
select count(city) - count(distinct city) as difference
from station;
```

[image]

**Explanation**: The query above is computing the arithmetic difference between the total number of cities - duplicates included - (`count(city)`) and the number of distinct cities (`count(distinct city)`), providing the expected result.